# Shipping estimate in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I host a website that has been up and running for years. It's worked fantastically up until now, but in the past couple days I had a very strange error arise.

In my shopping cart on magento, it gives the user the option of typing in the shipping zip code and getting an estimate on shipping. before the problems arose, the estimate shipping cost wouldn't appear until a zip code was typed. Now, it automatically defaults to $30.00 and I can't figure out how to fix it. I'm not sure if something was updated, like PHP, Magento, or some extension, but I need it fixed ASAP. I've been in Magento's admin area and changed shipping options, looked through tax options and everything I could possibly think of. I've even been in Magento's cart.phtml file and commented out the line:

`if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif;`

Doing this just takes the estimate shipping out completely. I don't want it out, I just want it to produce an estimate AFTER the zip code is typed in as opposed to before. I'm at a loss here, and my boss wants this done tomorrow. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

I've done everything i could possibly think of to fix the problem, even going as far as to completely replace the file with the original clean copy provided by magento. It's still defaulting to 30.00 shipping before anything is pressed; on page load. The site is using one step checkout as an extension on magento, and I'm completely at a loss with this one. I am guessing that it's a bug in the internal software because i've completely replaced all code with clean code except for core functionality of magento/one step checkout. Any input on it? Maybe i can make the radio button invisible until it's pressed? any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Take a look @ /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

Comment: thank you so much for the input. im looking now, and i will let you know if this solves my problem asap.

Comment: ok, this is the correct file. i believe that that's the file i need to edit. However, i'm having trouble understanding whats going on in it :/ its an extremely complex file. Any suggestions? I can edit that section out completely, but i have no idea how i would go about changing it so that it doesnt show up until the button is pressed. I know php pretty well. That's what i was hired to do; php. i just dont know magento at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, everything was set up as the default. It shows the maximum shipping price as the default in the file. The customer just didn't want it done that way. What i ended up doing was going to

`/app/design/frontend/default/scottsflowers/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

file and adding an ID to the radio button and its corresponding label and making them invisible from the time the page loads:

`<input id="radioone" name="estimate_method" style="display:'none';" type="radio"...`

`<label id="labelone" style="display:'none';"`

then i added a script shortly after those two items were placed in the code to check to see if the zip code was blank or if it had been filled in. If it was filled  in, make the two items visible. If not, keep them invisible. This is the code i used for that task:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                if (document.getElementById("postcode").value != "") {
                    document.getElementById("radioone").style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById("labelone").style.display='block';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("radioone").style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById("labelone").style.display='none';
                }
            </script>
```

problem solved. Although i was hired as a PHP programmer that was not required to do much, if any, front end work. This is quite frustrating since i'm not extremely comfortable with javscript in the first place. thank you all for the help. Your input pushed my research and understanding further along, and i wouldnt have been able to solve the problem if it werent for the answers i received on here.